# pass column name to dplyr filter function from within a function

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr

I'm writing a function to add some extra rows to a data frame i am building.

I've read many questions and answer's from previous OPs. But all answers, tips and tricks i found there do not work for me.

For this question i have the following test data frame:

```
tst <- data.frame("col 1" = c("a","a", "c"), "keyword test" = c("What", "Why", "how"), check.names = F)
> tst
  col 1 keyword test
1     a         What
2     a          Why
3     c          how
```

As you can see i have spaces in the data frame which i cannot remove, since the next tool is expecting spaces in the column names (DON'T ask me why!).

Now i want for example to filter all rows starting with "how" and replace "how" with "no_idea". This happens inside a temp DF. So that later on i can add the row `"c"  "no_idea"` to the original data frame.

The function i wrote for this looks like this:

```
add_keyword <- function(df, filterColumn, filterValue,replacement){
  library(plyr)
  library(dplyr)
  temp_df <- dplyr::filter_(df, filterColumn == filterValue)
  temp_df$`Target keyword` <- gsub(as.character(filterValue), as.character(replacement), temp_df$`Target keyword`)
  df_out <- rbind(df, temp_df)
  return(df_out)
}
```

`tst2 <- add_keyword(tst, "keyword test", "how", "no_idea")`

Of course if I run the lines inside the function outside the function it works perfect.

The result i would like to have inside `tst2`

```
> tst2
  col 1 keyword test
1     a         What
2     a         Why
3     c         how
4     c         no_idea
```

Comment: You are making it complicated by having column names that are not standard (i.e. having space in the column names)

Comment: @akrun I know it is complicated and it can be avoided that way. Im now thinking of changing the column names to without a space and add them back at the end when i am writing the table to be used with the other tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `interp` from `lazyeval`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)

add_keyword <- function(df, filterColumn, filterValue,replacement){
    temp_df <- df %>%
        filter_(interp(~ var == fval, var = as.name(filterColumn), fval = filterValue))

    temp_df[[filterColumn]] <- gsub(filterValue, replacement = replacement, temp_df[[filterColumn]])
    rbind(df, temp_df)
}
add_keyword(tst, "keyword test", "how", "no_idea")
#   col 1 keyword test
# 1     a         What
# 2     a          Why
# 3     c          how
# 4     c      no_idea
```

If we do not want to create additional rows, we can also try:

```
add_keyword <- function(df, filterColumn, filterValue, replacement){
    df <- df %>%
        mutate_(
            .dots = setNames(
                list(
                    interp(~ ifelse(startsWith(as.character(var), fval), rval, as.character(var)),
                           var = as.name(filterColumn), fval = filterValue, rval = replacement)),
                filterColumn
            )
        )
    df
}
add_keyword(tst, "keyword test", "how", "no_idea")


#   col 1 keyword test
# 1     a         What
# 2     a          Why
# 3     c      no_idea
```

Comment: this looks usefull indeed, one thing... i dont want to replace the row i want to add the replacement as a new row to the original data frame. But  i think i will manage with this code. Thanks!

Comment: Nice indeed. Looks clear. If i may ask, what to do if for example i want to replace my values inside another column. So i use one column to identify the rows and want to replace the value inside another column (sorry for to much extending my question, probably should write my question more clear next time)

Comment: I think you can add a new argument and change the line `temp_df[[filterColumn]] <- gsub(filterValue, replacement = replacement, temp_df[[filterColumn]])`

Comment: Haha, i was already doing that! Many thanks. Since you where the first one to answer i mark yours as the correct one!

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw, I remove the `paste` as I figured out how to specifiy values and variable names at the same time. This makes `interp` code more clean. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the devel version of `dplyr` (soon to be released 0.6.0) to make use of `quosure`s

```
add_keyword <- function(df, filterColumn, filterValue, replacement){
   filterColumn <- enquo(filterColumn)

   filtColumn <- quo_name(filterColumn)
   filterValue <- quo_name(enquo(filterValue))
   replacement <- quo_name(enquo(replacement))
   
   df %>%
       filter(UQ(filterColumn) ==  filterValue) %>%
       mutate(!!filtColumn  := gsub(filterValue, replacement, !!filterColumn)) %>%
       bind_rows(df, .)
       

 }
```

Except for the standard names, the unnatural column names can be passed with backquotes.

```
add_keyword(tst, `keyword test`, how, no_idea)
#   col 1 keyword test
#1     a         What
#2     a          Why
#3     c          how
#4     c      no_idea
```

Here, the `enquo` acts similar to `substitute` from `base R` by taking the input arguments and convert it to `quosure`.  We convert the quosure to string with `quo_name` and the value gets evaluated by unquoting (`UQ` or `!!`).

Checking for other values

```
add_keyword(tst, `keyword test`, how, new_idea)
#  col 1 keyword test
#1     a         What
#2     a          Why
#3     c          how
#4     c     new_idea

add_keyword(tst, `col 1`, a, z)
#  col 1 keyword test
#1     a         What
#2     a          Why
#3     c          how
#4     z         What
#5     z          Why
```

#### data

```
tst <- data.frame("col 1" = c("a","a", "c"), "keyword test" = c("What", "Why", "how"),
             check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for this elaborated answer. I like the dplyr package a lot so a full dplyr solution is always good. Since mt1022 was earlier with his answer i think the credits should go to him. Off course i will up vote yours as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

An easy trick, can't explain but write down the snippet below:

```
filter(df[, paste(filterColumn)] == filterValue)
```

This worked for me, hopefully works for you which looking for a solution :)